# How to change permission of mapped volume in kubernetes/Docker

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I just created image using Docker file and for changing user I just used:

```
USER myuser
```

We are using a directory to store data, we change that directory permission using:

```
chown -R myuser:myuser /data-dir
```

This Docker file is for etcd, where we want /data-dir use by etcd to store data. Now, we map the /data-dir to efs volume using kubernetes yml file.

With the below code:

```
volumeMounts:
        - name: etcdefs
          mountPath: /data-dir
      volumes:
      - name: etcdefs
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: efs-etcd
```

After this, I expect, that mapped directory /data-dir should have permission as myuser:myuser but it making the directory as root:root

Can any one suggest what I am doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is because of docker. It mounts volume with only root permission and you can change it with `chmod` but only after the container is started.

You can read more about it here https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/2259
This issues is here for a long time.

What you can do in kubernetes is use `fsGroup` and **force** that volume is writable by GID specified. This is working solution and documented as well. More information here https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/

Here is an example deployment:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: alpine
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: alpine
    spec:
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 1000
      containers:
        - name: alpine
          image: alpine
          volumeMounts:
              - mountPath: /var/alpine
                name: alpine
      volumes:
        - name: alpine
          awsElasticBlockStore:
            volumeID: vol-1234567890
            fsType: ext4
```

Comment: Hey, can you give me example of how to write to make use of  kubernetes with fsGroup. In my example give above

Comment: @SaganPariyar I have modified my answer and now it has example deployment using `fsGroup`

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, actually error was something else. Earlier we made docker images using root and while mapping it created directories using root, next time when I use myuser as the mapped volume already had directory created with root user so its giving the permission issue. I just delete the directory and recreated it with myuser and it works fine.

Comment: Good to hear you solve it. One thing that comes to my mind is that creating a directory in container will make you prone to changes in how docker mounts volume, with kubernetes `fsGroup` option you will be.

Comment: It should be noted that if you're using `minikube`, your PersistentVolume / PersistentVolumeClaim should use the default storage class. See: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/956#issuecomment-298859819

Comment: How about volume mounted from configMap?

Comment: What should be the volume ID "volumeID: vol-1234567890" in the case of Local - docker desktop ?

Comment: @happyyangyuan, looks like this feature doesn't support configMaps. "This field has no effect on ephemeral volume types such as secret, configMap, and emptydir." https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/#configure-volume-permission-and-ownership-change-policy-for-pods