# Kubernetes persistent volume overriding existing data in the pod/container

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes

We are trying to use kubernetes persistent volume mapped with pod/container directory to have as backup. Container directory (/home) already have data from dockerimage but when we mount kubernetes persistent volume with container directory(/home) the container data get override or vanishes.

***How to make kubernetes  persistent volume not to override data of container and only amend any data with pre-existing data?***

**cat pv.yml**

```
 apiVersion: v1
    kind: PersistentVolume
    metadata:
      name: task-pv-volume
      labels:
        type: local
    spec:
      storageClassName: manual
      capacity:
        storage: 10Gi
      accessModes:
        - ReadWriteOnce
      hostPath:
        path: "/home/xyz/dock/main/kube/storage"
```

**cat pvclaim.yml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: task-pv-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 3Gi
```

**Below is main manifest file which deploys pods with persistent volume**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mypod
spec:
  volumes:
    - name: task-pv-storage
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: task-pv-claim
    - name: cgroup
      hostPath:
        path: /sys/fs/cgroup
        type: Directory
  containers:
    - name: rbf-container
      image: 10.190.205.11:5000/myimage/ubuntu:1.0
      securityContext:
        privileged: true
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/home/xyz"      ##-> mounting persistent volume with container directory /home/xyz**
          name: task-pv-storage
        - mountPath: /sys/fs/cgroup
          name: cgroup
```

**output with kubernetes persistent volume:**

```
$ ssh 10.244.4.29
Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/home/xyz/.ssh/known_hosts).
xyz@10.244.4.29's password:
Last login: Tue Aug 25 11:16:48 2020 from 10.252.85.167
$ bash
To run a command as administrator (user "root"), use "sudo <command>".
See "man sudo_root" for details.

xyz@mypod:~$ ls
xyz@mypod:~$ ls -l
total 0                    ##--> no data present it all get vanished
xyz@mypod:~$ pwd
/home/xyz
```

**Output from pod without persistent volume**

```
$ ssh 10.244.4.29
Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/home/xyz/.ssh/known_hosts).
xyz@10.244.4.29's password:
Last login: Tue Aug 25 11:16:48 2020 from 10.252.85.167
$ bash
To run a command as administrator (user "root"), use "sudo <command>".
See "man sudo_root" for details.

xyz@mypod:~$ ls
xyz@mypod:~$ ls -l
total 465780
drwxrwxrwx 1 xyz xyz      4096 Aug 13 12:44 Desktop
drwxr-xr-x 2 xyz xyz      4096 Aug 25 11:12 Documents
drwxr-xr-x 2 xyz xyz      4096 Aug 25 11:12 Downloads
drwxr-xr-x 2 xyz xyz      4096 Aug 25 11:12 Music
drwxr-xr-x 2 xyz xyz      4096 Aug 25 11:12 Pictures
drwxr-xr-x 2 xyz xyz      4096 Aug 25 11:12 Public
drwxr-xr-x 2 xyz xyz      4096 Aug 25 11:12 Templates
drwxr-xr-x 2 xyz xyz      4096 Aug 25 11:12 Videos
-rw------- 1 xyz xyz   2404352 Aug 25 11:12 core
drwx------ 4 root root      4096 Aug 10 08:39 local.bak
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 474439680 Aug 10 08:35 local.tar
```

**As you can see data from dockerimage is available without using persistent volume**

Comment: It may be problem with perrmissions. Did you see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46974105/kubernetes-setting-custom-permissions-file-ownership-per-volume-and-not-per-p and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46769339/how-to-change-permission-of-mapped-volume-in-kubernetes-docker ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm only at the beginning of my Kubernetes journey and still trying to grasp the best practices, but I think what you're trying to do is not possible (in the case of /home to /home). AFAIK the data is not overwritten, but exists "under" the mount. You can try this yourself by mounting a folder with `mount --bind folder_a folder_b` and then unmounting the folder with `umount folder_b`. Creating the mount hides the files in folder_b, but unmounting makes them appear again.

So that would mean that you just need to initialize the volume by copying the files to the volume. You can achieve this with `kubectl exec <pod> -- <command>`, or by running a [job](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/), or with [initContainers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/), or by using an entrypoint shell script. Since copying files over and over again to the mounted volume is waste of energy, I'd think that first two options are preferred.